# how to exclude stopwords from collections of texts nltk

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to exclude the `stopwords` from the collection of texts. As you can see from the bottom, `t` holds these texts. I check if the words in the texts are not in `stopword` list then return the words that are not in the `stopwords`.
However, when I run the program it shows all the words with `stopwords`.

```
t = [
(text,word)    
for text in ['1861-Lincoln.txt','1865-Lincoln.txt', '1933Roosevelt.txt','1937-Roosevelt.txt','1941-Roosevelt.txt','1945-Roosevelt.txt','1981-Reagan.txt','1985-Reagan.txt'
]

for word in inaugural.words(text)]

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopW = stopwords.words('english')

def exludingStopwords(tx):
      c = [w for w in tx if w not in stopW]
      return c

exludingStopwords(t)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/README.md and https://github.com/interrogator/wwc/blob/master/session-01.ipynb and http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

Comment: Avoid functional looping, you are doing it very wrong

Comment: Apologies for my bad programming manner. I try to learn from the mistakes.

Comment: Stopword removal with the nltk is a common question, but I could not find one that has a concise and correct answer for the basic task with an nltk corpus. If anyone finds one, please mark this question as duplicate. (In the meantime, I have provided an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the functional looping in a very bad manner;

I suggest to filter like that:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stop = stopwords.words('english')
>>> textfiles = ['1861-Lincoln.txt','1865-Lincoln.txt', '1933Roosevelt.txt','1937-Roosevelt.txt','1941-Roosevelt.txt','1945-Roosevelt.txt','1981-Reagan.txt','1985-Reagan.txt' ]
>>> text = "".join(map(lambda x: open(x).read(s), textfiles))
>>> print [i for i in text.split() if i not in stop]
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I am not using such files. I am using corpus(inaugural) to get those txt files.

Comment: (1) joining with `""` risks sticking words together (when a file doesn't end with a newline). (2) str.split() will leave punctuation attached to words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting stuck or what your objection to @bigOTHER's solution is, but here is a canonical way to remove stopwords from an nltk corpus:

```
stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english"))

cleanwords = [ w for w in nltk.corpus.inaugural.words() if w.lower() not in stopwords ]
```

That's all there is to it. Note that I made a set of the stopwords: It speeds things up enormously.

To work with a subset of the inaugural texts, provide a list of them as the argument of `inaugural.words()`. To remove punctuation as well, use this variation:

```
cleanwords = [ wrd for wrd in nltk.corpus.inaugural.words() if 
        wrd.lower() not in stopwords and re.search(r"\w", wrd)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom code excludes stopwords and punctuation
****************************Code*************************

listOfTexts = [ '1861-Lincoln.txt','1865-Lincoln.txt', '1933-Roosevelt.txt',
                '1937-Roosevelt.txt','1941-Roosevelt.txt']

allTextWords = [word for text in listOfTexts for word in inaugural.words(text)]

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopW = stopwords.words('english')

clean_words = [w for w in allTextWords if w.lower() not in stopW and w.lower() if w.isalpha()]